# How to find all sockets in room using the latest version of Socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

So, using socket.io **version < 1.0** you could use:

```
var clients = io.sockets.clients('room');
```

To get all sockets in the room 'room'.

However now with the lastest version of socket.io this is not possible, I haven't found a solution yet that works for the latest version and I do not wish to downgrade versions to run my application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        var clients= io.sockets.adapter.rooms[room].sockets
```

Seems to do the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Socket [Redis Adapter](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-redis) for manage SocketIO rooms.

```
const io = require('socket.io')(3000);
const redisAdapter = require('socket.io-redis');
io.adapter(redisAdapter({ host: 'localhost', port: 6379 }));

io.on('connection', function(client) {
    //Get allRooms by Redis Adapter
    io.of('/').adapter.allRooms((err, rooms) => {
        for (let room of rooms) {
             //Handle your room
        }
    })
})
```

Hope this help!

Comment: This might be a good solution if you are already using Redis pubsub, but adding a Redis database to a project just so you can get a list of clients in a room is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

according to the [socket.io 2.0 docs](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace-clients-callback)

```js
io.in('room').clients((error, clients) => {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log(clients); // => [Anw2LatarvGVVXEIAAAD]
});
```

and to get the socket for the client-id:

```
io.sockets.sockets[client]
```

(yes, 2 times sockets)